# Given an operation $F:A\to B$ and $X \subseteq A$, how to prove that $\{F(x) \mid x \in X\}$ is a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that:

> Given an operation $F:A \rightarrow B$, and given that $X \subseteq A$, the collection $Y = \{F(x):x \in X \}$ is a set.

I assumed, that, in order to prove that a collection is a set, one should show that it satisfies the ZF axioms. (am I right?)
I have a problem proving the The collection Y, satisfies axiom 3 of ZF, which is separation (specification). 
I am trying to show that given a property $ \psi $, The collection, $\{ \psi(y);y \in F(x) \}$ is a set. But' trying to do that, I encounter the need, to use the statement which I am trying to prove.. any help?

An **Operation**, $F$ from $A$ to $B$ is a rule that, adjusts, for every $a \in A$ a unique $b \in B$. in a similar way to functions, we will say that $F$ is one to one if $F(a)=F(b) \Rightarrow a=b$ also $Im(F)=\{ f(A); A \in A \}$ and $F$ is onto $B$ if $Im(F) = B$

Thanks, Shir

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "operation"?

Comment: It is also not clear what you mean by "proving an axiom". Are you trying to deduce it from some other set of axioms?

Comment: And what relation does there exist between $\;A,B,X\;$ ...?

Answer (score 1):

As Trevor Wilson [pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544225/given-an-operation-fa-to-b-and-x-subseteq-a-how-to-prove-that-fx-mi#comment1159130_544225) in the comments, the Axiom of Replacement is the way to go. What remains to be done after its application will depend on the exact formulation of the Axiom you are using.